# Ant creates wrong buildnumber

Tags: java, javascript, xml, ant, webstorm

I have a build.xml file that has taks like, release, clean, debug, compress and buildnumber,
All tasks work fine but buildnumber task is not right, I think.

This is how my buildnumber task looks like in the build.xml file:

```
<target name="buildnumber">
    <echo>Creating buildnumber</echo>
    <propertyfile file="${basedir}/build/version.properties" >
        <entry key="Build" type="int" default="0" operation="+"/>
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

This task gets only called when I do release:

```
<target name="release" description="compile for deployment">
    <antcall target="clean" />
    <antcall target="buildnumber">
        <param name="increment" value="Build"/>
    </antcall>
```

If I call this ant from Eclipse it creates a minified js file like this
 **mygame-0.0.0-min.js** 
so the buildnumber that is the last number in my case (0.0.**0**) does not get incremented.
If I call ant from Webstorm I got this minified file:
**mygame-0.0.71-min.js**.
I mean how is this possible? Buildnumber should not increment because this task is not called by ant because I do no **release** just  **"clean" , "debug" and "compress"** .

Here is how my **version.properties** file looks like:

```
## Version properties
Version=1
Patch=0
Build=0
```

What is going wrong with my build.xml file? What am I missing?

Comment: Can't say as you don't show where you read the version.properties file, and how you generate the name of your js file.  (Also, I'm not sure what the param you supply to the buildnumber target is for, as it's not used in the target. Don't think that matters here though.)

Comment: @martinclayton I think there is a problem using File Watchers within Webstorm
File Watchers runs every time I save my changed js Files and it runs ant like in an infinite loop
I just still have no clue what is wrong

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the standard build number ANT task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html